# Installing plugin offline Angular 4

Tags: angular

In my development machine, internet is disabled due to security reason. But we have lots of Angular plugins installed already. But I need another one which is Angular2-select2 plugin. Here is the github link for the plugin.

[Angular2-select2](https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2)

There is an option for downloading as zip file there itself. But my question is where to extract that zip file in the application. Straight to the node_modules folder? After placing it in that folder what I have to do to use that plugin. Please share some solution..

Comment: Easiest is to install properly outside the firewall, zip up that complete install including installed dependencies, then take that zip to your project.

Answer (score 0):

just move the extracted folder to your node_modules and add Angular2-select2 with the exact version to your package.json

and make sure you have a jquery plugin too.

Comment: I'm not so sure, look at the dependencies in Angular2-select2 package.json, those are needed too.

Comment: yeah needed those dependencies too i forget to mention thanks for pointing it out.